# смена владельца файла и группы внутри phar

Tags: php

Делаю класс - обертку над потоком для взаимодействия с phar архивом. При реализации метода stream_metadata столкнулся с проблемой: chown и chgrp не работают с файлами:

```
chown('phar://path_to_phar.tar.gz/file.name', 'user_name');
```

> chown(): Can not call chown() for a non-standard stream

Comment: господи, зачем вам менять права внутри phar-архива?

Answer (score 1):

Что такое phar-архив? Это просто tar-архив, в который завернуты php-исходники, и который php умеет исполнять. Несмотря на то, что его можно открыть сродни папки **изнутри** PHP, для файловой системы это **один** файл. Для файловой системы **нет** вложенных файлов, потому поменять их атрибуты, в том числе владельца и разрешения, **невозможно**.

Если это делалось с неакадемическими целями, то стоит задать именно тот вопрос, который стоял за принятием решения делать `chmod` внутри архива.

Comment: chmod как раз можно делать - http://php.net/manual/en/pharfileinfo.chmod.php. Я спрашивал про chown. StreamWrapper::set_metadata может быть вызван для смены владельца файла - поэтому такой вопрос.

Comment: Окей,описался, `chown`,